# jQuery Load div on hover and be able to interact with that div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a hover to load in social feeds for Facebook & Twitter.

I have got the jQuery together. But I am having a problem that as soon as a user hovers out of the button it fades out and you cannot click the information.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujBZY/) for this and as you can see, You hover over the a.social it loads the content in. But as soon as you try to interact with the loaded DIV it dissapears.

How can I make it so that the user can still click on the information within the opened div?

jQuery Code is as follows :

```
$(".social_facebook").css('display','none');
$(".social_twitter").css('display','none');

    $('a.facebook').hover(function() {
        $('.social_facebook').fadeIn("slow");
    }, function() {
        $('.social_facebook').fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $('a.twitter').hover(function() {
        $('.social_twitter').fadeIn("slow");
    }, function() {
        $('.social_twitter').fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

This is wrapped within a document.ready function..

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I suppose you could use .show() method http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you wanted to show either one of those, if so try below approach.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujBZY/15/)

```
$(".social_facebook").css('display','none');
$(".social_twitter").css('display','none');

$('a.facebook').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.social_twitter').fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $('.social_facebook').fadeIn("slow");
    });        
});

$('a.twitter').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.social_facebook').fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $('.social_twitter').fadeIn("slow");
    });        
});

 //Added
$('.social_facebook, .social_twitter').mouseout(function () {
   $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: Apologies... On mouse out I'd like it to hide the DIV content. Didnt say that in my question

Comment: @StuBlackett On mouse out of which element? Your code will hide when you mouse out of the `a`. Do you want to hide on mouse out of the `.social_twitter` or `.social_facebook`

Comment: Yeah on mouse out hide whichever div is active. social_twitter or social_facebook dependant on which one it is.

Comment: That is just about right. Although the Facebook or Twitter still seems to appear when moving around the page

Answer (score 1):

Because you have set the `mouseout` method to hide the `div` without realizing it.
The second function parameter for the `$.hover` method is actually telling it what to do when the mouse leaves the target.

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ujBZY/2/

To hide them both when you leave the "area" just define a wrapper element and add a `mouseout` to it:

```
$('.main-area').mouseout(function() {
    $('.social_facebook').hide();
    $('.social_twitter').hide();
});
```

Keep in mind your social elements have to be within that area, so you will have to change some of their display properties.

Comment: Thats more like it.. But what about when you mouse completley out of that area? Would like to then hide the shown div. Apologies not explained in question

Comment: Hi @TerryR I'm not too sure what you're suggesting here. I wrap a .main-area div around the social links? Then hide them when the mouse dissapears from there?

Comment: You said "But what about when you mouse completley out of that area?"  You have to define what "that area" means.  If you mean an area of your webpage, define it with a parent HTML element and hide the divs when their mouse leaves the larger area (rather than the individual social elements)

Comment: Sure. Will take a look at that

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ujBZY/9/

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li.social {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:visible;
}
 a {
    display: block;
    height: 61px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    width: 61px;
}

.social_facebook, .social_twitter {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.sociallinks {
    float: right;
}

.facebook {
    background: url(http://i44.tinypic.com/smys80.png) no-repeat;
}

.twitter {
    background: url(http://i44.tinypic.com/10fno04.png) no-repeat;
}
<div class="span5">
    <div class="sociallinks">
        <ul>
            <li class="social"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="facebook" title="Join Us on Facebook">Join us on Facebook</a>
                <!-- Hidden Social Feeds -->
                <div class="social_facebook">
                        FACEBOOK HERE
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="social"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="twitter" title="Follow Us on Twitter">Follow us on Twitter</a>
                <div class="social_twitter">    
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/" title="Follow us on Twitter">Latest Tweet</a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en" data-size="large">Follow @twitter</a>

                    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>  
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>                
    </div>
</div>


$(".social_facebook").css('display','none');
$(".social_twitter").css('display','none');

$('.social').hover(function() {
    $('div', this).stop().fadeIn("slow");
}, function() {
    $('div', this).stop().fadeOut("slow");
});
```